# How to create a blob view inside an already being displayed document from the @react-pdf package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-pdf

I want to create a base64 encoded PDF view inside of here:

```
.....
    <Document pdfMode={pdfMode}>
      <Page className="invoice-wrapper" pdfMode={pdfMode}>
        {!pdfMode && <Download data={invoice} />}

        <View className="flex" pdfMode={pdfMode}>
          {/* Render a PDF Blob here */}
        </View>

        <View className="flex mt-40" pdfMode={pdfMode}>
          <View className="w-55" pdfMode={pdfMode}>
.....
```

Basically, I am trying to mix a base64 encoded PDF with the PDF I am building. Help.